# Extract data from a sequence of bytes

Tags: delphi, header, serial-port

Assume we have a sequence of bytes with header of '807F' which is input to PC through RS232. for example "... 80 7F 4B 97 **80 7F 21 3A** 80 7F ... " in which "21 3A" is our data in bold package and 21 is MSB and 3A is LSB. how can we extract data from the sequence in DELPHI?

Comment: What data structure are you using to hold the sequence of bytes?

Comment: I intend to find '80 7F' and push 4 bytes after that. if it's not the answer of your question, what do you mean by data structure?

Comment: You want to find '80 7F' but find it in what? In a `TBytes`? In a string? With just a pointer to the first byte of some buffer? In a file? In a stream?

Comment: as I said, it comes from serial port. so it's in a stream. and its type is string. but I can receive it byte per byte in string format. such as '80' or '7F'

Comment: Do you have any code at all? Is it a stream or a string?

Comment: I meant it comes online from external device. but as we know, serial port have internal buffer which at first data comes there and after that we read data from that buffer. I read from that buffer in string format.

Comment: OK, in that case search through the buffer until you find the bytes you are looking for

Comment: Assume you can read a byte from buffer with this function: a=readbyte(). can you tell me what's your desired code?

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me that you have any code at all. If you did surely you would have posted it by now in the question. It's impossible to help you if you are unable to specify the problem.

Comment: @Garry Mc: edit and extend youre question

Comment: -1 For now, for not being able to edit the question properly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Do you mean I post code of unpacking data or what? my question is really obvious. there is a external device which we connect it to PC through RS232 PORT at 9600 baud rate and it send data with the structure of '807FXXXX' in which XXXX is our data.

Comment: Are these data in ASCII or hex format ? In other words, are you getting 8 or 4 data bytes ?

Comment: every package contain 8 bytes in HEX format. when system interrupts that new data received, I read 2 bytes entirely by this code: `for i:=0 to received-1 do
data:= IntToHex(Byte(PChar(Buffer)[i]),2);`

Comment: @gerry "my question is really obvious". It might be obvious to you, but it is as clear as mud to everyone else.

Comment: @GarryMc - what happens if 'when system interrupts that new data received' only one char has been received?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How your data is stored is a bit unclear, but assuming it is stored in a `TBytes` array, here is some code to unpack the data:

```
procedure ExtractWordFromRS232Data( a : TBytes);
var
  i: integer;
  myWord: word;
begin
  // a is a TBytes buffer from reading the RS232 port
  i := 0;
  while (i < Length(a)-3) do 
  begin
    if (a[i] = $80) and (a[i+1] = $7F) then 
    begin
      myWord := (a[i+2] shl 8) + a[i+3];
      // Do something with myWord
      Inc(i,4);
    end
    else
      Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

It will search for first excistance of the header $80 $7F and unpack the following two bytes into a `word`. Do what you want with the word. The search then continues until the end of the input data array.

Update:
It's still unclear what you really want, but here is some code where data is coming to the procedure via an event.

```
var
  gData : array[1..4] of byte;
  gIX : integer;

gIx := 1; // initialized at start

procedure InterpretIndataEvent( b : byte);
var
  i : integer;
  myWord : word;
begin
  gData[gIx] := b;
  if (gIx = 4) then
  begin
    if (gData[1] = $80) and (gData[2] = $7f) then
    begin
      myWord := (gData[3] shl 8) + gData[4];
      // do something with myWord
      gIx := 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      for i := 1 to 3 do gData[i] := gData[i+1];
    end;
  end
  else
    Inc(gIx);
end;
```

**Update 2:**

By the look of the comments, it seems as though the data is coming as ascii characters.

Then the decoding procedure will look something like this (including a small test) :

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  gData : string[8] = '12345678'; // Old fixed size ansistring type
  gIX : integer = 1;

procedure InterpretIndataEvent( a : AnsiChar);
var
  i : integer;
  myWord : word;
begin
  gData[gIx] := a;
  if (gIx = 8) then
  begin
    if (Copy(gData,1,4) = '807F') then
    begin
      myWord := StrToInt('$'+Copy(gData,5,4));
      // do something with myWord
      WriteLn(IntToHex(myWord,4));
      gIx := 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      for i := 1 to 7 do gData[i] := gData[i+1];
      // During startup or if a character is missed we end up here.
      // These events can be logged from here.
    end;
  end
  else
    Inc(gIx);
end;

const
  testBuf : string[8] = '807F213A';
var
  i : integer;

begin
  for i := 1 to 8 do
    InterpretIndataEvent(testBuf[i]);
  ReadLn;

end.
```

Comment: @DorinDuminica, sorry I do not understand what you mean ?

Comment: 'was kidding (: most likely he "has" the data in a AnsiString, so **var** lbytes: **array of** byte **absolute** Value; where Value is an AnsiString

Comment: If the incoming data is a serial stream, it's possible that a protocol unit spans up to four buffers.

Comment: @DorinDuminica, Ok, but using ansistring for data is not supposed to happen since Delphi2009 :)

Comment: @MartinJames, would you elaborate a bit about the four buffers. I have  implemented more than 100 real time serial protocols over the years, but never heard of this.

Comment: @LU RD, your code will work when I have whole the sequence of data as a stored file. but if I receive data from external device online, when I receive '80', I don't know what next byte is. as you declare, a is a TByte, so I have to store every 10 bytes and after that use your function. but I think 2 packages will unpack(8 bytes) and 2 other bytes will missed. am I right? (sorry I forget to say, data is in AnsiString format)

Comment: To use this procedure, you will need a minimum of 4 bytes stored in `a`. Why are you saying you have to store every 10 bytes? If it is possible for your sequences to span multiple incoming buffers, then this routine alone is insufficient for identifying your data.

Comment: Garry, I will update the code first thing tomorrow to reflect the AnsiChar data input.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I assume...

```
program project;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

const
  DATA_HEADER = Word(Swap($807F));

type
  TData = Word;
  TDataCallback = procedure(const aData: TData);

  PDataStruct = ^TDataStruct;
  TDataStruct = packed record
    Header: Word;
    Data: TData
  end;

procedure DecodeData(const aData: Pointer; const aDataSize: Integer;
  const aCallback: TDataCallback);
type
  PDataBuffer = ^TDataBuffer;
  TDataBuffer = packed array[0..High(Integer)-1] of Byte;
var
  Ix: Integer;
  Data: PDataStruct;
begin
  if not Assigned(aCallback) then
     Exit; // WARRNING: program flow disorder

  Ix := 0;
  while (Ix <= aDataSize - SizeOf(TDataStruct)) do
  begin

    Data:= @PDataBuffer(aData)^[Ix];
    if Data^.Header = DATA_HEADER then
    begin

      aCallback(Swap(Data^.Data));
      Inc(Ix, SizeOf(Data^));

    end
    else
      Inc(Ix)

  end
end;

var
  W: TData = 0;

procedure ProcessData(const aData: TData);
begin
  Inc(W, aData)
end;

var
  InputIx: Integer = 0;

// youre serial input
function ReadByte(): Byte;
const
  DATA: packed array[0..11] of Byte = (
    $80, $7F, $4B, $97, $80, $7F, $21, $3A, $80, $7F, $AB, $CD);
begin
  Result:= DATA[InputIx];
  InputIx:= (InputIx + 1) mod SizeOf(DATA);
end;

var
  Buffer: packed record
    case Byte of
      0: (
        Data: TDataStruct);
      1: (
        Raw: array[0..Pred(SizeOf(TDataStruct))] of Byte)
  end;

var
  Ix: Integer;
begin
  while true do
  begin

    for Ix := Low(Buffer.Raw) to High(Buffer.Raw) do
    begin

      Buffer.Raw[Ix]:= ReadByte()

    end;
    DecodeData(
      @Buffer,
      SizeOf(Buffer),
      @ProcessData)

  end
end.
```

But reading you input by Byte may be a little uneffective.